# Is it possible to install the latest Amd Crimson Edition Proprietary Drivers?

Tags: drivers, ati, proprietary, crimson

Is it possible to install the latest Amd Crimson Edition Proprietary Drivers ?
I tried many times (downloaded the driver from amd) but couldn't build dkms ! (i've installed all the required packages)
I tried ubuntu 16.04 , 15.10

Comment: Found working solution for my radeon R9 390x here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2321874&p=13515588#post13515588

Answer (score 0):

The proprietary AMD drivers are not officially supported in 16.04. It's recommended you use an earlier Ubuntu.

However, you shouldn't use 15.10, since it's not an LTS version. LTS versions get security updates for five years. Non-LTS versions get security updates for nine months. 15.10 will stop getting security updates late this month.

Use 14.04 LTS. It's supported until 2019.